# YouTube stutters and stops frequently

Tags: youtube

Lately, YouTube has become increasingly tedious to use.

I have a very good connection—100Mbps—and I get 70-80 actual when measuring and other sites load very quick.

When starting to stream a video on YouTube, it starts to stutter almost immediately. Then if I pause it, it only buffers a small part, then stops. Even worse, sometimes it seems like the entire video is ready to be watched, but it ends too soon. For example, a 45 minute video is ends after only 5 minutes.

Has anyone else experienced this new and poor behavior from YouTube? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Dude, where did you get such a good connection????

Comment: @pattyd Possibly some ISP in America, or a company/organization. The University I work at always gets at least this connection speed, and it is Canadian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YouTube HTML5 Video Player does a much better job of buffering than the default Adobe Flash Player, enabling the entire video to be buffered, which should eliminate your stuttering problem. You can enable the YouTube HTML5 Video Player by default [here](https://www.youtube.com/html5).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a few days just out of the blue, but when I found out I was in the HTML5 Alpha test I disabled it and no more video stuttering.